# Strange output from gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I ran gcc (within a makefile) and I got a lot of this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
```

What is that for kind of error?

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766256/g-returning-relocation-has-an-invalid-symbol-at-symbol-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the major reason for this error is that you have a missing `main()` function.

```
int main()
{
  // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hey, you posted that after my comment and got a +1, should have been mine :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl:- I was typing my answer while you posted the link. Posting a link could take lesser time then posting an answer. BTW post an answer and I will give you +1 :) Also to mention that this was one of the bug which I always came across in my early school days ;)